# Prove a transformation is skew-symmetric

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

This is exercise 6 section 5.5 on Apostol Calculus II :

> Let $C(0,1)$ be the real linear space of all real functions defined on [0,1] with inner product $(f,g) = \int_0^1 f(t)g(t)dt$. Let $V$ be the subspace of functions such that $\int_0^1 f(t)dt = 0$, and $T: V \rightarrow C$ be $\int_0^x f(t)dt$. Prove that $T$ is skew-symmetric.

I think that I'm supposed to show $\int_0^1 f(t)Tg(t) + Tf(t)g(t)dt = 0$ but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Note that $Tf$ is differentiable with $(Tf)' = f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^1 \left( f(Tg) + (Tf)g \right) (x) dx = \int_0^1 \left( f(x) \left( \int_0^x g(t)dt \right) + \left( \int_0^x f(t)dt \right) g(x) \right) dx = \int_0^1 \left( \left( \int_0^x f(t)dt \right)'_x \left( \int_0^x g(t)dt \right) + \left( \int_0^x f(t)dt \right) \left( \int_0^x g(t)dt \right)'_x \right) dx = \left. \left( \int_0^x f(t)dt \int_0^x g(t)dt \right) \right\vert_0^1 = \int_0^1 f(t)dt \int_0^1 g(t)dt = 0.$$

Comment: Where does that last step follow from? Because I got to a similar relation through integration by parts, but never realized that $\int_0^x f(t)dt \int_0^x g(t)dt = 0$

Comment: I added one more intermediate step to the answer. Recall the definition of $V$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which tells us that $$\frac{d}{dx}\bigl[Tf(x)\bigr]=f(x).$$ Then, the product rule lets us rewrite $$f(t)Tg(t)+Tf(t)g(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\bigl[Tf(t)\bigr]Tg(t)+Tf(t)\frac{d}{dt}\bigl[Tg(t)\bigr]=\frac{d}{dt}\bigl[Tf(t)Tg(t)\bigr].$$ Keeping in mind that $f,g\in V,$ can you take it from there?